# in Foreach Loop the Description is not showing?

Tags: loop

in my index.php page, i used this code but its not showing description ie: 100 characters of my articles? Don't recommend replacing get_the_content() with $post->post_content, i know that works. but need correct output keeping get_the_content().let me know what other thing should i change in this code to get the output.

```
<?php
$args = array('posts_per_page'=>3,
    'orderby'=>'rand',
    'post_type'=>'post'
);

$post_data = get_posts($args);

foreach($post_data as $post){

    echo '<a href="'.get_the_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a><br>';

    $post_data = substr(strip_tags(get_the_content()),0,100).'...';
    echo $post_data."<br>";

}
?>
```

Comment: What output do you get? substr in the post_content isn't the best approach as it could lead to breaking the word.

Comment: @Drupalizeme as i said, i am getting everything in output except the 100 characters description.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please read about the [get_the_permalink](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_permalink/) and [get_the_title](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_title/). These functions are developed to fetch the details from global $post variable. Your local $post won't be effective here.

You should either pass local `$post` to these functions like `get_the_permalink($post)` and `get_the_title($post)`. For get_the_content, you will need to use `apply_filters('the_content',$post->post_content);`

However, preferred way is to create an object of [WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query). Please read about its a powerful class to query everything about posts. In your case, it will look something like this

```
<?php
$args = array('posts_per_page'=>3,
    'orderby'=>'rand',
    'post_type'=>'post'
);

$randomPosts = new WP_Query($args);

while($randomPosts->have_posts()){
    $randomPosts->the_post();

    echo '<a href="'.get_the_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a><br>';

    echo substr(strip_tags(get_the_content()),0,100).'...';
    echo "<br>";

}
?>
```

I have not tested above code but, I guess, you get the idea.

Comment: get_the_content should work as well, try removing substr and strip_tags if it is returning post contents and there is not issue with the post data.

Comment: thanks man it worked. i just posted 1 more small question. if you could answer that as well. thanks alot.